# chrome.webRequest redirectUrl with URL Saved in chrome.storage.local

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to intercept web requests and redirect them to a url I have saved on local storage but it isn't working. My code is as follows:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    function (details) {
        if (details.url === 'http://myapp.com/theurl') {
            chrome.storage.local.get("http://myapp.com/theurl", function (result) {
                return { redirectUrl: result.savedUrl }; //savedUrl property is the modified Url
            });
        }
    }, { urls: ["<all_urls>"] }, ["blocking"]);
```

Hardcoding the return statement/url works:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    function (details) {
        if (details.url === 'http://myapp.com/theurl') {
                return { returnUrl : 'http://myapp.com/modifiedurl' };
            });
        }
    }, { urls: ["<all_urls>"] }, ["blocking"]);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `chrome.storage` api is [asynchronous](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage), so the approach that you are taking here will not work. The basic run-through of what is happening with the code you have is:

1. Before the webrequest, check if the url is `http://myapp.com/theurl`
2. If it is, then make an asynchronous call to `chrome.storage.local.get`
3. The code inside your `chrome.storage.local.get` call (ie. the return statement) is not executed immediately and will be run at some later time
4. The rest of your code continues to run and nothing is returned from your webRequest listener

There are a couple of ways that you can make this work. The easiest would be to store the values of the local storage inside some variable when your extension is loaded (call it, say, `storage_cache`). Then from the webRequest listener you could say `return { redirectUrl: storage_cache.savedUrl };`

If your storage will change frequently then there are better approaches than this one...but the key thing to remember for whatever implementation your choose is to not to mix up synchronous and asynchronous events.

Comment: I agree that `storage_cache` is the way to go. Only one thing to add, that it's easy to maintain the cache with a listener to `chrome.storage.onChanged`.

Comment: I read that adding ["blocking"] should make request synchronous. 
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest

Comment: The problem is not with the webRequest listener (and here "blocking" is something else entirely). The problem is that `chrome.storage.local.get` is *always* executed asynchronously, and the code in your listener is written as if it is not. Your code _would_ work if it executed sequentially, but since there is an async call in there the simple fact is that it does not! Try out the `storage_cache` idea, I have used a similar pattern in my extensions and it seems to be the best solution.

Comment: yepp i've cached the storage and it did fix my problem. thanks!