# Block URL's from the list with webRequest onBeforeRequest, but it is'nt blocking

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, webrequest

I'm trying to block all request, what is exist is the Local Storage list. 
On the options page, we can add words. If the loaded url contains the words, the extension will cancel the request.
The script is working until blocking request, but the webpage load without any error.

The background script is running, but the pages are loaded. What's wrong in my code?

**backgound.js:**

```
var urls = ["*://*/*"];
Kezd.addListener(function(details) {
console.log(details.url);
chrome.storage.local.get('cimek', function(items) {
    var urlek = [];
    if (items.cimek) {
        cims = items.cimek;
        result = cims.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/);
        for (i = 0; i <=result.length-1; i++ ){
            urlek.push(result[i]);
        }
    }else {return {cancel: false};}

    chrome.storage.local.get('ad', function(itemms) {
        console.log("Storage rendben");
        console.log(urls);
        if (itemms.ad) {
            if (itemms.ad == 0) {
                console.log("Listener torolve...");
                return {cancel: false};
            }else{
                if (details.url.indexOf(urlek) > -1){
                        console.log("Sikeres/Successful");
                        return {cancel: true};
                    }else{
                        console.log("Listener kihagyva...");
                        return {cancel: false};
                    }
                //}

            }
        } else {return {cancel: false};}
    });
});
},{urls},["blocking"]);
```

and the **options.js**:

```
var helyi = chrome.storage.local;
var rGomb = document.querySelector('button.reset');
var MentGomb = document.querySelector('button.submit');
var Text = document.querySelector('textarea');

betoltes(); //load()

MentGomb.addEventListener('click', Mentes);
rGomb.addEventListener('click', reset);

function Mentes() {
  var cimek = Text.value;
  var result = 1;
  if (!cimek) {
    uzenet('Hiba: Nincs megadva semmi');
    return;
  }
            helyi.set({'cimek': cimek}, function() {
            uzenet('Beállítások mentve');});
            helyi.set({'ad': result}, function(){});
  }

function betoltes() {
  helyi.get('cimek', function(items) {
    if (items.cimek) {
      Text.value = items.cimek;
      uzenet('Mentett adatok betöltve');
    }
  });
    }

function reset() {
  helyi.remove('cimek', function(items) {
    uzenet('Reset végrehajtva');
  });
  var result = 0;
  helyi.set({'ad': result}, function(){});
  // Frissítés
  Text.value = '';
}

function uzenet(msg) {
  var uzenet = document.querySelector('.message');
  uzenet.innerText = msg;
  setTimeout(function() {
    uzenet.innerText = '';
  }, 3000);
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Duplicate of [chrome.webRequest redirectUrl with URL Saved in chrome.storage.local](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24132061) or [Asynchronous operation in blocking chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders listener](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29153685)

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33681539/executing-asynchronous-function-synchronously/33681875

Comment: Going by seniority, closing with the oldest of three